# untargeted bind vs. `toInstance()` bind

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

I'm new to Guice and I'm not sure I understand the difference between

1) untargeted bind - when do I need to use this?

```
bind(Logger.class);
```

2 )'toInstance()` bind - how do I init an object that has ctor with dependencies? or is it for data object with no dependencies only?

```
bind(Logger.class).toInstance(new Logger(..?..));
```

3) not writing any bind in the

```
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
}
```

what happens in any of the above when I run

and when should I choose any of them?

Answer (score 5):

1. Untargetted bindings: you rarely *need* to use them, but they're necessary if

   - You want to specify a scope (`bind(Untargetted.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);`, for example)
   - You want to keep the binding inside a [`PrivateModule`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html)
   - You have [required explicit bindings](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requireExplicitBindings--)
2. You're right, generally you can't use `toInstance()` for objects with constructor dependencies.  It's more useful for non-Guicey objects like data objects or library classes you have to create with `new`.
3. When you inject a type that is not bound in any `Module`, Guice creates a [just-in-time binding](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings) for it.  The behaviour is almost identical to `bind(Untargetted.class);`

The major difference between untargetted and `toInstance()` bindings is that `toInstance()` bindings will be singletons ("obviously" -- there's only one instance!), but untargetted bindings, like most other bindings, have no scope by default.  So if different classes inject an `Untargetted`, they'll get different instances unless you put a scope on it.

Another difference is that when you don't use `toInstance()`, Guice creates the instance for you, enabling things like [aspect-oriented programming](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP).

Generally, you should prefer not to use `toInstance()` bindings unless you have to.  Untargetted bindings have the advantage of being more explicit, but it can be verbose to list them all, so just-in-time bindings are often used instead.  Especially in cases like this:

```
bind(Interface.class)
        .to(Implementation.class);

// Technically, Guice creates a just-in-time binding for Implementation here
```