# Google Guice Untargetted Bindings

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

My question is more of just asking for a simple working example of an untargetted(spelling on purpose with reference to google guice wiki) binding. So far I have looked all over the internet and have failed to find an example of one. The Google guice wiki doesn't explain in-depth how untargetted bindings work and I am stuck on the learning process for this. I understand that you must bind a Concrete class in the module but from there I don't understand what class would be able to pick it up or how it would pick it up as actual injection. Please help, thanks.

Comment: There are pretty explanatory answers on SO already on the subject, did you check them?
[one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27559999/6099243)
[two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32595062/6099243)

Comment: I did see them but none of them had examples of where the injection is being picked up. Just shows the binding module. Also do you bring the actual interface class or the implementation class for the untargetted binding